# identity VS identifier in c++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, identity, terminology, identifier

When learning [Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), the term `identity` confuses me.

I know that `identifier` is well-defined in the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name

> An identifier is an arbitrarily long sequence of letters and digits.

---

But it doesn't define what is `identity`. Here lists several places `identity` occur:

1. **value category**:

   > A glvalue is an expression whose evaluation determines the **identity** of an object, bit-field, or function.
2. **linkage** [6.5]

   > (10.4) — when both names denote function templates, the signatures (17.6.6.1) are the same.
   >   11 After all adjustments of types (during which typedefs (10.1.3) are replaced by their definitions), the types
   >   specified by all declarations referring to a given variable or function shall be identical, except that declarations
   >   for an array object can specify array types that differ by the presence or absence of a major array bound (11.3.4).
   >   A violation of this rule on type **identity** does not require a diagnostic.
3. **Identity conversions** [23.17.7.9.5 ]

---

[Stack overflow tag: identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/identifier/info) (no one updates):

> An identifier is a name that identifies either a unique object or a unique class of objects.

[Stack overflow tag: identity](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/identity/info):

> An inherent property of an entity that distinguishes that entity from all others. Frequently used to refer to user identity and authentication.

Are the two terms the same?

- If they are, why standard doesn't use the same one?
- If they are not, what's the difference?

Comment: You can have multiple symbols with the same *identifier* at different scopes, and use different *identity* to access them. For example if you have a global variable `x` and a local variable with the same name, then plain `x` identify the identifier in the closest scope, while `::x` identify the global identifier.

Comment: "Identity" is just a plain English word.